# Making the custom marker in google maps curved at the bottom like a pin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am using a custom image as marker for pin in a google maps project.But the pin is shown as the rectangular image.But i want it to be curved at the bottom.Is there a way to make it curved.

The code i am using for the marker is shown below:

```
public class retrieveimage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
Store_data s;
MarkerOptions marker;
Bitmap pinbit;
    public retrieveimage(Store_data s) {
        this.s=s;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
             marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.store_latitude),Double.parseDouble(s.store_longitude))).title(s.store_name);
            String url1=arg0[0];
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            pinbit=bitmap;



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pinbit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pinbit,75,56,false);
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pinbit));
      // adding marker

      googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this curved image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use icon for google maps marker with transpanent parts, somethink like this [image] If it doesn't help you, try to make rounded image from code:

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


    return output;
}
```

Comment: I got it to work.But it doesnt give me the pin at the bottom i want.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want more detail and i will try to help you